# a href attribute for Skype chat

Tags: href, skype

I am trying to create an a tag leading to Skype chat.
The problem is that Skype did not give me an ID. People find me only using my first and last name. 
I tried this but it didn't work.

```
<a href="skype:John Doe?chat">
```

see the null space? John &nbsp Doe.

How can I type it so it works properly?

E.g: **I do not want** to use my phone number.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright so I found a workaround.
I added myself from a new account to see what is my Id.

It has this form live:b3e263c856585e34 .

So I used this `<a href="skype:live:b3e263c856585e34?chat">` and it worked fine.
Strange but it works

Answer (score 0):

The values need to be escaped. `<a href="skype:John%20Doe?chat">`